# SQL resultset processing

Tags: java, sql, resultset

Can someone help me with this SQL. 
I "should" have one record, in fact, I know I have one record, but the code is falling thru to the catch expression.

okay...I modified code and getting same results. Falling thru to exception

```
<%
String sqlpminfo = "select ea.PreferredName, ea.LastName, ea.AreaCityCode, ea.PhoneNo, eemail.EmployeeEmailAddress from Program p join ProgramXXXEmployeeRole pxxx on pxxx.ProgramID = p.ProgramID and pxxx.RoleCode=799 join EmployeeAdmin ea on ea.XXXEmployeeCode = pxxx.XXXEmployeeCode join EmployeeEmail eemail on eemail.XXXEmployeeCode = pxxx.XXXEmployeeCode where p.ProgramID=" + formFields.getValue("programID");

  try { 
        log.info(sqlpminfo);
        log.info("programID: " + formFields.getValue("programID"));
        QueryWrap pmwrap = new QueryWrap();
        ResultSet pmrt = pmwrap.executeQueryWithException(sqlpminfo);
                if (pmrt == null || pmrt.equals(""))
                 {  pmrt.close();


         }
         else
         {
            int i = 0;
            while ( pmrt.next() )
            {
                        String pmFname = pmrt.getString(1);
                        String pmLname = pmrt.getString(2);
                        String pmAreacode = pmrt.getString(3);
                        String pmPhone = pmrt.getString(4);
                        String pmemail = pmrt.getString(5);
                        log.info ("PM Contact: " + pmrt.getString(1) + " " + pmrt.getString(2) );

                        %>
                        Name:  <%=pmFname%> <%=pmLname%> <br/>
                        Email: <a href="mailto:<%=pmemail%>"><%=pmemail%></a><br/>

                        Phone: (<%=pmAreacode%>) 
                        <%if (pmPhone.length() == 7) {%><%=pmPhone.substring(0, 3)%>-<%=pmPhone.substring(3, 7)%>   <%} else {%><%=pmPhone%><%} %>
                        <br/><br/>
                        <%

                        i++;
                     } //end of while

                    pmrt.close();
                    if(i == 0)
            {
             %>
                            Contact Information is not available. Please email <br/>
                        <%
            }
                } //end if if 

        } catch (Exception ee) {
                        %>
            log.error("caught exception in PMcontactinfo: " + e);



<%  }%>
```

Comment: After further troubleshooting, it was discovered that I had a permissions issue with one of my tables...it was actually a view. The tables that then compose that view also have permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

pmrt.last() : Moves the cursor to the last row in the resultset.
pmrt.getRow() : Returns the row number. If you have 10 matching results, this will give 10 in your scenario.
pmrt.beforeFirst() : Will again set the cursor to before first row of the resultset. You can use pmrt.next() to get the first row in the resultset now.

Can you paste the exception you got here.

Comment: @ChannaJayamuni  and DheerajKumarGopa thank you for your assistance. I made some modifications, but my code is still failing/falling thru to catch. When I pull the SQL statement from my logs, I can execute it in SQL studio and get the record. It doesn't want to work in jsp.

Answer (score 0):

**Behavior of `ResultSet` java**

Consider a shelf of books when you going to find a book starting from left side.

[image]

1. When you are starting to find you are not at the first book. You are at the before of first book. In relation to the `ResultSet` it says the `beforeFirst` position of the `ResultSet`. `ResultSet` allows to point this position by calling `beforeFirst()` method. You cannot get the row number since you are not started to iterate.
2. When you calling `next()` method of the `ResultSet` to moves the cursor into the first row, similarly when seeing at the first book of the shelf. Additionally you can locate the first book of the shelf, similarly `ResultSet` allows to set pointer into the first row by calling `first()` method.
3. After checking the first book you are going to check **next** book. Similarly `ResultSet` allows move cursor into next row by calling `next()` method.
4. Think if you have reached the last book of the shelf. Can you check the next book? No, because there is no book exists after the last row. As same as you cannot call `next()` method of `ResultSet` when the cursor at the last row.
5. Additionally `next()` method of `ResultSet` returns a `boolean` value to indicate are there any more rows exists. It returns `false` when no more rows exist.
6. You can identify the last book as same as the first book of the shelf. Similarly `ResultSet` allows to point the last row by calling `last()` method.